# ASP.NET Core - TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,...]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core EF Code First I am trying to customize the IdentityDbContext by Changing the Tkey to long, I have:

```
public class DDMDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, long, IdentityUserClaim<long>, ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<long>, IdentityRoleClaim<long>, IdentityUserToken<long>>
{
    public DDMDbContext(DbContextOptions<DDMDbContext> options)
    : base(options) { }

    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationRole> ApplicationRole { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ApplicationUserRole> ApplicationUserRole { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);      

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(m => m.Id).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>(userRole =>
        {
            userRole.HasKey(ur => new { ur.UserId, ur.RoleId });

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.Role)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.RoleId)
                .IsRequired();

            userRole.HasOne(ur => ur.User)
                .WithMany(r => r.UserRoles)
                .HasForeignKey(ur => ur.UserId)
                .IsRequired();
        });

    }
}

namespace DDM.API.Core.Data.Identity
{
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<long>
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<long>
    {
        public ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; set; }
    }

    public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<long>
    {
        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
        public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Howevr, I got this error when I tried to add-migration:

> An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: GenericArguments[0], 'Data.Identity.ApplicationUser', on 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore.UserStore`9[TUser,TRole,TContext,TKey,TUserClaim,TUserRole,TUserLogin,TUserToken,TRoleClaim]' violates the constraint of type 'TUser'.

How do I get this sorted our?

Thanks

Comment: Did you build the project before the add-migration?

Comment: @JHBonarius - Yes I did

Comment: Why are you doing all the scaffolding yourself? And why are your redefining all generic parameters, even though they are not all that different? [If you look at the docs (at the bottom), it shouldn't be much work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model)

Comment: Did you modify the default model of Identity, and then perform code first for migration?